# SMTP relaying: avoid antispam filter using Amazon SES (or similar tools)

Tags: email, smtp, spam, amazon-ses, spf

Our web application is an HR management app in which the user (typically an hr manager) can insert some SMTP credentials and send mail through our app (our app use javamail to handle the message sending) to the personal email addresses of his workers.

So, different users insert different SMTP credentials, but some of these use SMTP servers which are not designed to send massive number of mails (we are talking about not great numbers, hundreds) in a short span of time, so typically we have logs in which the SMTP rejects the messages with various errors of policy violations.

I thought that using a thirdy party service like [Amazon SES](http://aws.amazon.com/ses/), which offer a smtp who will not reject our messages could be a solution to our problem.

So, imagining that our app has two users

- **user 1**

  - *user1@userdomain.com*
- **user 1**

  - *user2@anotheruserdomain.com*

and each of these users has 10 workers with releted email addresses (or various domains like gmail, yahoo, etc).

We would use the Amazon SES SMTP to relay those mails using as sender address user1@userdomain.com or user2@anotheruserdomain.com to all the workers addresses.

But I fear that the gmail, yahoo, etc servers will probably check if the smtp who sent the message (**amazonses** in this case) is authorized to send mail of the sender domain (userdomain.com or anotheruserdomain.com).

Such a check I think is called SPF check, to avoid email spoofing.

**Is there a way to avoid this, considering that I cannot access the userdomain.com and anotheruserdomain.com domain settings?**

Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the spoofing issue by sending emails in your own name. The industry best practice is to use your own email address for delivery and only impersonate the sender in the email header. When you deliver an email using SMTP, you can specify a `MAIL FROM address` (also called the "envelope sender", "Return-Path" or P1 sender address), which may be different from the `"From:"` (MIME From) address in the email header.

In this model, emails from Amazon SES would be sent with the MAIL FROM address of `send-bounces-here@yourdomain.com` and the `From:` address would be `user1@userdomain.com`. As SPF checks are ran against the MAIL FROM address and never the MIME "From:", the emails will not be considered spoofed, as long as they satisfy the SPF policy of yourdomain.com, if any.

This practice is commonly employed by mailing lists and email newsletters. By using a unique sender address for each email (e.g. bounces-guid@yourdomain.com), you can even do automated bounce tracking for each email sent, a technique called [Variable Envelope Return-Path (VERP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_envelope_return_path).

Comment: I guess this is what we did, correct me if I'm wrong:

We signed up on Sendgrid Lite plan (we don't send that many email, 10.000 per month are enough) so we used the sendgrid smtp credentials and only set the From: property.

I inspected a test mail that I sent to my inbox using this method and it says:

Delivered-to: <my_mail@address.com>
Return-path: <bounces+7489384_etc_my_mail=address.com@sendgrid.me>
From: <impersonated_sender@sender.com>


Is that correct?

Comment: That looks correct (they even seem to use VERP). Using a reputable third-party for delivering emails is also a good choice, they usually have their hard-earned experience needed for high deliverability. BTW sorry about the late response, I just came across your question.